# Is there a function to prevent a JS file from loading in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm currently running a Wordpress website and i'm trying to get the best results in terms of speed/score in pageinsights. However, there are a few scripts that keep on loading !

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this exact file from loading in the page, is a such thing possible ?

Thank you

Comment: You could simply delete the file from your server, but be careful: your site might not work if you delete some essential component.

Comment: Well that looks like a good idea, except i need the script for other pages, that is why i need to disable it on specific pages !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, there is a function in Wordpress to disable script. Kindly see the link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/

Comment: Thank you. Seems interesting, i'll make sure to try it !